# AngularJS: Taking old values instead of new during put

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When updating, I want to insert new values coming from the ui instead of old values present in the local collection. The below code inserts old values in local collection(I don't want this to happen).

```
dataService.getSupplierById($routeParams.id)
.then(function (supplier) {
    $scope.supplier = supplier; //now this contains local collection

    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.updatedSupplier = $scope.supplier; //I want the scope to be updated and take values from the ui

        dataService.updateSupplier($routeParams.id, $scope.updatedSupplier)
        .then(function () {
            //success

        },
            function () {
                //error

            });
    };
},
function () {
    //error
});
```

This is my Html.

```
<div>
    <label for="City">City</label>
    <input name="City" type="text" data-ng-model="updateSupplier.city" value="{{supplier.city}}" />
</div>
```

How can I do this? How can I update the scope to take new values? I'm new to angular.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. :(

Comment: Are you trying to get the new values ?

Comment: I want to take the new values from the ui. But how can i add those new values to my scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding to `updateSupplier` as the `ng-model` then you shouldn't overwrite the values when you save:

```
$scope.save = function () {

    // remove the line that overwrites, was here    

    dataService.updateSupplier($routeParams.id, $scope.updatedSupplier)
        .then(function () {
            //success
        },
        function () {
            //error
        });
    };
}
```

Angular will take care of two-way binding the value inside the `ng-model` so by the time you save it will have the correct value that was input in the textbox.

You can also clean up the code by not have 2 different scope properties:

```
dataService.getSupplierById($routeParams.id)
.then(function (supplier) {
    $scope.supplier = supplier; //now this contains local collection

    $scope.save = function () {

        dataService.updateSupplier($routeParams.id, $scope.supplier )
        .then(function () {
            //success

        },
            function () {
                //error

            });
    };
},
function () {
    //error
});
```

And then in the html:

```
<div>
    <label for="City">City</label>
    <input name="City" type="text" data-ng-model="supplier.city" />
</div>
```

The initial value should bind into the `value` attribute automatically.